# Pandas groupby apply anomaly with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

While experimenting Pandas in Jupyter, I noticed very strange symptom. I reduce it down to a bare minimum code that demonstrates the symptom:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'B': [datetime(2018, 11, 1), datetime(2018, 11, 2), datetime(2018, 11, 3) ]
})
df

    A   B
0   a   2018-11-01
1   b   2018-11-02
2   c   2018-11-03

def process(gdf):
    return pd.Series({
        'C': datetime(2018, 11, 5)
    })
df2 = df.groupby(['A']).apply(process).reset_index()
df2

    A   C
0   a   1541376000000000000
1   b   1541376000000000000
2   c   1541376000000000000

df2['C']

0    1541376000000000000
1    1541376000000000000
2    1541376000000000000
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

As you can see, the `C` column ended up being `int64` type instead of the expected `datetime64[ns]` type. But if I don't have the `B` column then `C` column correctly ends up being `datetime64[ns]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    # 'B': [datetime(2018, 11, 1), datetime(2018, 11, 2), datetime(2018, 11, 3) ]
})
df

    A
0   a
1   b
2   c

def process(gdf):
    return pd.Series({
        'C': datetime(2018, 11, 5)
    })
df2 = df.groupby(['A']).apply(process).reset_index()
df2

    A   C
0   a   2018-11-05
1   b   2018-11-05
2   c   2018-11-05

df2['C']

0   2018-11-05
1   2018-11-05
2   2018-11-05
Name: C, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I have no clue what is happening. Anyone any idea? I'm using Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.23.1

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and I cannot reproduce it. Also the first output is `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it seems bug.

In my opinion here is possible create new column for each group and return not Series, but `gdp` group:

```
def process(gdf):
    gdf['C'] = datetime(2018, 11, 5)
    return gdf

df2 = df.groupby(['A']).apply(process)
print (df2)
   A          B          C
0  a 2018-11-01 2018-11-05
1  b 2018-11-02 2018-11-05
2  c 2018-11-03 2018-11-05
```